# need adice with errors on phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

Whenever I logged into my phpmyadmin and select SQL, I get the following errors and can't seem to fix it.

> Warning in .\libraries\classes\Dbi\DbiMysqli.php#250
>    mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given
>   Backtrace
>   .\libraries\classes\Dbi\DbiMysqli.php#250: mysqli_fetch_array(
>   boolean true,
>   integer 1,
>   )
>   .\libraries\classes\DatabaseInterface.php#2579: PhpMyAdmin\Dbi\DbiMysqli->fetchAssoc(boolean true)
>   .\libraries\classes\DatabaseInterface.php#1805: PhpMyAdmin\DatabaseInterface->fetchAssoc(boolean true)
>   .\libraries\classes\ListDatabase.php#89: PhpMyAdmin\DatabaseInterface->fetchResult(
>   string 'SELECT `SCHEMA_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`SCHEMATA`',
>   NULL,
>   NULL,
>   )
>   .\libraries\classes\ListDatabase.php#112: PhpMyAdmin\ListDatabase->retrieve()
>   .\libraries\classes\ListDatabase.php#35: PhpMyAdmin\ListDatabase->build()
>   .\libraries\classes\Database\DatabaseList.php#53: PhpMyAdmin\ListDatabase->__construct()
>   .\libraries\classes\Database\DatabaseList.php#39: PhpMyAdmin\Database\DatabaseList->getDatabaseList()
>   .\libraries\classes\DatabaseInterface.php#1586: PhpMyAdmin\Database\DatabaseList->__get(string 'databases')
>   .\libraries\classes\DatabaseInterface.php#2519: PhpMyAdmin\DatabaseInterface->postConnectControl()
>   .\libraries\common.inc.php#380: PhpMyAdmin\DatabaseInterface->connect(
>   integer 256,
>   array,
>   integer 257,
>   )
>   .\server_sql.php#15: require_once(.\libraries\common.inc.php)

I've tried reinstalling the software and windows Still nothing works.

Any ideas on how can I solve this?

Comment: Have you deleted any DB? Can you make sure that `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` still exists and is accessible?

Comment: Hello, no, this just came up when I logged into phpmyadmin, it was a fresh install and just started saying that. I tried with 2 different versions of windows and all the same. I really don't know what to do

Comment: Your PHP installation must be misconfigured. How did you install it? Which extensions are loaded in? Give us more information, so we can help you.